# How to retrieve a Boolean value from Firebase to a TextView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a shopping app and User has to subscribe to the 'Fast-delivery' option if he needs to order it faster. When the User puts a tick to the 'Fast-delivery' Checkbox, the boolean value is being uploaded to the Firebase realtime database -->
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSczT.png)

And I want to see if the User has subscribed to the 'Fast-delivery' option from the Admin Panel. I retrieve all the order information to a RecyclerView in the Admin Panel. I want to set a TextView as "Fast Delivery : On/Off" when the Admin views the order details from the Admin Panel.

This is what I have tried:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdminOrders> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminOrders>()
            .setQuery(ordersRef, AdminOrders.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminOrders, AdminOrdersViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminOrders, AdminOrdersViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdminOrdersViewHolder holder, final int position, final @NonNull AdminOrders model)
                {
                    holder.userName.setText("Name: "+ model.getName());
                    holder.userPhoneNumber.setText("Phone Number: : "+ model.getPhone());
                    holder.userTotalPrice.setText("Total Amount: $"+ model.getTotalAmount());
                    holder.userDateTime.setText("Order Time: "+ model.getDate() + model.getTime());
                    holder.userShippingAddress.setText("Shipping Address: "+ model.getAddress() + "," + model.getCity());
                    holder.showOrdersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            String uID = getRef(position).getKey();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminNewOrdersActivity.this, AdminUserProductsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("uid", uID);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });


                    ordersRef.child(userID).child("fast_delivery").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            TextView switch1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                            switch1.setText(String.valueOf(this));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
```

And I'm getting this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Sorry @AlexMamo I edited the problem

Answer (score 2):

You have a `NullPointerException` indicating that `userID` is not initialized, hence this error:

> Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

To solve this, please add the following line of code:

```
String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Right in front of:

```
ordersRef.child(userID).child("fast_delivery").addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess if im right.. you have created separate tree for orders where you are getting orders

create model class **give name as same as childname are** where you're getting boolean value of **fast_delivery** use that boolean value to convert it to string and hence compare that value if **String.valueof(boolean)is="true"** then print to textview or vise versa with **off**